# Sikuli4Net Unable to connect to remote server c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, automation, sikuli, sikuli-script

I need help, I followed all the steps correctly and examples but I did not find solution to this error.
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused them 127.0.0.1:8080.

- Firewall disabled
- vs 2010
- net 4.0
- SIKULI_HOME C:\sikuli
- Newtonsoft.Json -Version 6.0.4

  ```
      private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          APILauncher launcher = new APILauncher();
          launcher.Start();
          Sikuli4Net.sikuli_REST.Screen s = new Sikuli4Net.sikuli_REST.Screen();
          Pattern ee = new Pattern(@"\img\a.png");
          s.Click(ee);
          //Start API Launcher
          launcher.Stop();
      }
  ```